# NotFoundHttpException for Controller route in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get started using controllers in Laravel 4 and I am running into some trouble.  Here is the basic run down:

I have a controller in the controllers folder called FansController in the file FansController.php:

```
<php

class FansController extends BaseController {

        public $restful = true

        public function getindex() {
        return View::make('fans.landing');
    }
}
```

Within my views folder, I have a folder called "fans" that controls a view file "landing.blade.php".  It contains simple html:  `<h1>hello</h1>`

In my routes.php file, I have a route calling the controller.  Here is that code:

```
Route::get('landing', array('uses' => 'FansController@index'));
```

When I visit the url: public/fans/landing

I receive a "NotFoundHttpException";

Do you have any ideas what may be going wrong?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off you need to specify what version of Laravel you are running.

If you are running Laravel 4 then:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'GuestController@getIndex'));

// GuestController.php
class GuestController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex() {
         return 'Hello world.';
    }
}
```

Then run `$ composer dump-autoload -o` or `php composer.phar dump-autoload -o` (if your composer is installed locally) on your CLI

In laravel 3, however

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'GuestController@index'));

// GuestController.php
class GuestController extends BaseController {
    public $restful = true;
    public function get_index() {
         return 'Hello world.';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running 4.  I will try this.

Comment: Okay let me know the outcome

Comment: Ok, it is still not working, but in addition, I don't want to route to go to '/', I want it to go to the view I specified, landing.  Could you give a solution that works with that?

Comment: Can I still use: return View::make('fans.landing');  ?

Comment: Yes you can. Provided you have a corresponding file at > ./app/views/fans/landing.blade.php

Comment: This is so the composer autoloader can find your new controller. If your question was solved, tick it as okay :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31779/discussion-between-neo-ighodaro-and-user1072337)

Comment: It hasn't...it still says FansController does not exist at public/landing

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change your method name to index:

```
class FansController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true

    public function index() {
        return View::make('fans.landing');
    }

}
```

Comment: but isn't that what the "$restful" line is for?  I thought $restful tells the controller to respond to the "get" string when it is called in the route.

Comment: This also did not solve the problem.  Also, going to public/landing, it says FansController does not exist.  But it very clearly does...

Comment: restful is default now in L4, so index() is restful and I use it all the time so I'm pretty sure it's right. About FansController not existing, it may just not be available to autoload, check your file vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php, it must be there or Laravel won't find it.

Comment: It is not...but neither is another controller that I'm using, AccountController.php, and that is working just fine.  There is nothing in the documentation saying that I need to add new controller to that file.